# how to create a property that counts every letter in every word in an array

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a @State private var usedWords = String

this array store the history of words that are used in the game

I have a property that counts the letters of every single letter in each word from the above array by using .count

I want to create a new variable that counts every letter in all the words in the above array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have state property your solution mb like this:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State var usedWords = [String]()
        
    var lettersCount: Int {
        usedWords.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.count }
    }

    ...
}
```

Every change of usedWords property will trigger view redraw and recalculation of lettersCount computed property, thats why view will always use actual value of lettersCount.
Letters counting was used from JLM answer.

Comment: ok it works but I want to reset it every game so I added "score = 0" to my startGame function and I got this error Cannot assign to property: 'score' is a get-only property

Comment: @Hamza i think better to drop usedWords values for each new game, on some action do usedWords = [], it will lead to update lettersCount to 0

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the array instance method reduce. Example:

```
let names = ["Jessica", "Nick", "Layla", "Elanor"]
let count = names.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.count }
```

Comment: I get error :Cannot use instance member 'usedWords' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available , I think I get this because the name constant for me is a var that add stuff to the array every time someone enter

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
usedWords.joined(separator: "").count
```

Complete example:

```
struct SomeView: View {
   @State var usedWords = [String]()

  var body: some View {
     VStack {
        Text("\(usedWords.joined(separator: "").count)")
        Button {
            let words = ["Swift", "Objective C", "Kotlin", "Java", "Javascript", "Dart"]
            usedWords.append(words[Int.random(in: 0..<words.count)])
        } label: {
            Text("Add Word")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I get this error:Cannot use instance member 'usedWords' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: Added a complete example.